# How to remove items in a drop down based on an ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down box in my view which I would like to alter depending on the ClientID. I don't have a clue where to start with this, I thought about using Javascript but I would rather avoid it as some users could have Javascript turned off.

ViewModel:

```
   public class ReportType {
        public int ReportID { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReportType> ReportTypeOptions = new List<ReportType>
    {
        new ReportType {ReportID = 0, ReportName = "Claims by Supplier"},
        new ReportType {ReportID = 1, ReportName = "Department Breakdown"},
        new ReportType {ReportID = 2, ReportName = "Reason Code Breakdown"},
        new ReportType {ReportID = 3, ReportName = "Monthly Debiting Report"},
    };
```

View:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportTypeOptions.First().ReportID, new SelectList(Model.ReportTypeOptions, "ReportID", "ReportName"), "Select Report", new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD", onchange = "disableFunction()" })
```

Comment: "some users could have Javascript turned off" very unlikely scenario

Comment: @naveen True but thats not that point

Comment: could you elaborate the question? what id, what sort of filtering... things like that

Comment: @naveen I have a ClientID which I need to check on my view. And depending on the ClientID. I need to be able to either remove or disable the Monthly Debiting Report

Comment: @AndrewKilburn You can chk all ur condition on controller and then pass a list through view bag and use that to bind the drop-down list